# Block that stay in line no matter the size of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row that does not stay in line when the window get very narrow.
the green block goes under the other block, is this normal behavior?

I mean I though that because it is in a `"row"` class and because I use `xs` column that add up to 12 it should stay in line whatever the size of the screen.

Here my code (or you can go to [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/0QljcFfEwI))

```
    <div class="row" style="height:150px">  
      <div class="col-xs-1 bggrey" style="height:100%"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 bgblue" style="height:100%"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 bgred" style="height:100%"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 bggreen" style="height:100%"></div>
    </div>
```

What I expect from my code (working fine if window not too narrow)
[image]

What I get if window is narrowed
[image]

Comment: Please include your CSS in the question. That said, this is most probably due to the way the browser is calculating percentages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think is a problem of the default paddings in the divs. When the resolution is smallest than the sum of all paddings it broken. In your code there are 4 divs, with 30 pixels of padding, and when it is so fit, it broken. I put paddings to zero value and it works

See this: http://www.bootply.com/jaSQxxUZuD#

The only change in css is

```
  .row > div { padding: 0 }
```

If you need to conserve theese paddings, you can prevent broken line:

```
  .row { white-space: nowrap; }
```

## EDIT

If you need to conserve these paddings, it's better make the innerbox

```
  .row > div { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

With this last class, you preserve paddings, but the width will not be incremented like without paddings.

Comment: ok, work with "padding:0" but cannot get it the expected result when using "white-space:nowrap";

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. With whitespace it works if `col-* ` is display:inline-block, and it's not. Forget it

Comment: I make an edit in my answer, maybe if you want to preserve paddings your solution is box-sizing. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

`col-xs-1` has a `padding-left` and `padding-right` of 15px, this means that the size of the gray bar is bigger than 8.333% of the width when the screen width goes below 330px.

Set padding to 0 to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are different possibilities to solve this.
Adding this to the css should at least do it:

```
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-6{
    padding:0px;
}
```